# Build universal path for all operating systems

Tags: python, path

This is my code

```
path = r'C:/Users/user/documents/data'

def new_name(path, keyword, ext="csv"):
    return ('\\'.join(path.split("\\")[:-1]) + "\\" + path.split("\\")[-1].split(".")[0] + keyword + "." + ext)


new_path = new_name(path, '_test')
print(new_path)
>>> \C:/Users/user/documents/data_test.csv # Output
C:/Users/user/documents/data_test.csv # What I want
```

I get a path with a file and I would like to add a keyword to this file. Does this option also exist with Pathlib (or something like that)?
Since this path doesn't work properly on Mac, I would like to build a more universal solution.

Answer (score 0):

The [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators) module (Python 3.4+) is your friend when working with paths in Python.

In special, the class [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path):

> This class represents concrete paths of the system’s path flavour (instantiating it creates either a PosixPath or a WindowsPath).

Which means that you don't have to worry about OS-specific path details such as forward/backward slashes.

So the above example could be rewritten as:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('C:/Users/user/documents/data')

def new_name(path, keyword, ext="csv"):
    return Path(str(path) + keyword + '.' + ext)

new_path = new_name(path, '_test')
print(new_path)

>>> C:/Users/user/documents/data_test.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the **os.path.join** command in this case

for example:
Assume you are running a script from **C:\temp**
and want to load **"file_name=inputfile.json"** from .**/json** folder.
You need to concatenate the paths to get one absolute path to the filename:  **C:\temp\json\inputfile.json**

Code would look like:

```
from os import path

file_name = "inpoutfile.json"
abs_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"json", file_name) 
print (abs_file_path)
```

result is:
C:\temp\json\inputfile.json